# How to import posts of external url to Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, jsp, plugins

I've built a new website using Wordpress system for developing.
I want to import posts from old site which is non-wordpress external site.
Because there are too many posts on non-wordpress site (maybe over 4,000 posts), so I cannot copy so many posts from the old site to the new site one by one.
New site URL(Wordpress): http://kcsaa.muvy.com.tw/
Old site URL(.JSP File): http://www.kcsaa.org.tw/context_single2.jsp?sla=2046

My question is how to import the posts of non-wordpress site to wordpress site easily and quickly?
By the way, I hope there is a way to solve this problem by using browser extensions or Wordpress plugins actually.

Thank you guys!!

Comment: Need help, please!

Comment: moving a java project to wordpress, that's sacrilege.

Answer (score 1):

If you can export the posts from the non-wordpress site to an .xml or .csv file you able to import it into WordPress. There are some great plugins to import .xml or .csv files.

I used this plugin a couple of times and it worked pretty nice: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Make sure your .xml or .csv file includes the images paths. Otherwise you loose all images.

Before you import the posts create a full backup.